# how to use packages with are organized in stacks with catkin?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can I use packages with are organized in "old-style" stacks within packages with are build with catkin? e.g. gps_common which is within the stack gps_umd. rospack does find it, but not find_package(gps_common REQUIRED).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52009/how-to-use-packages-with-are-organized-in-stacks-with-catkin?/) by [mifritscher](https://answers.ros.org/users/3945/mifritscher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, you can't. Catkin packages ("wet", new-style) can only depend on catkin packages (or regular CMake) while stacks ("dry", old-style) can depend on other stacks (using rosbuild & manifest.xml) and catkin packages (using CMake). Thus the need to slowly convert packages from the bottom of the dependency chain upwards to "wet" packages, like a rising water level.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5